# Missing url field using Solr DataImportHandler

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler, dih

I'm new to Solr and having difficulties with the DataImportHandler. I get this message when the server starts:
Jan 27, 2010 12:27:22 PM org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler processConfiguration

> INFO: Processing configuration from solrconfig.xml: {config=dih-gensigdb-jdbc.xml}
>   Jan 27, 2010 12:27:22 PM org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter loadDataConfig
>   INFO: Data Configuration loaded successfully
>   Jan 27, 2010 12:27:22 PM org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter verifyWithSchema
>   INFO: url is a required field in SolrSchema . But not found in DataConfig

My dataConfig doesnt contain a url field, but i'm not sure why its required. When i use the DIH console and try to debug the config I get the following errors during document import:

> org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Document [null] missing required field: url

My dataConfig looks like this:
`<dataConfig>
    <dataSource name="jdbc" driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
       url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"
           user="genesigdb" password="genesigdb"/>
    <document name="PMID">
       <entity name="PMID" dataSource="jdbc" query="SELECT PMID FROM PUBLICATION">
       </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found what this issue was, in the schema.xml file there is an field called unique key which should correlate with the PK of your entity in the dataConfig.xml

Comment: Same problem, in my `schema.xml` field was `id` and in my table it was `product_id`. I changed it now its working....thanks a ton